# Assign is not working as expected when recoding data frame variables?

Tags: r, global-variables, variable-assignment, assign, assignment-operator

I've been having an issue where I've been trying to recode many variables at once. What seemed the easiest way to do things was to use `assign` and place the variable in `.GlobalEnv`. I now see that it's not even working outside of the function.

Does anyone have any idea why,

```
assign('dataframe$col1', 3 - dataframe$col1, env = .GlobalEnv)
```

seems to have no effect on `dataframe$col1`?

Comment: It is better to use `[` rather than `$`

Comment: What is the reasoning behind that? I'm extremely new to R.

Comment: In this case, you were not using the arguments in the correct way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `assign`, this can be done in a complicated way

```
 assign('dataframe', `[[<-`(dataframe, 'col',
              value = 3- dataframe$col), envir=.GlobalEnv)

 dataframe$col
 #[1]  2  1  0 -1 -2
```

Less complicated and safer would be

```
 dataframe$col <- 3-dataframe$col
```

Or if you are using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(dataframe)[, col:= 3- col]
```

and the `dplyr/magrittr` option is

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(magrittr)
 dataframe %<>%
         mutate(col = 3 - col)
```

#### data

```
 dataframe <- data.frame(col= 1:5)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I'd tried a variation of this earlier with `get` that I saw from a different answer but `assign` kept telling me I didn't have a valid argument. This generalizes very well to my function for reverse coding variables as well.

Comment: @Marcus `get` is needed if you are passing a `string`

Comment: You were so fast that I was told I had to wait five minutes to accept your answer.

Comment: @Marcus Thanks, I forgot about the holding time :-)